# Using jQuery to hide/show products using a switch statement and radio buttons

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, show-hide

So I have a store web page and I'm trying to add jQuery to select and show specific items when a radio button is selected using a switch function.  For some reason it is not working.  When I run the code it's not doing anything and just shows all the products listed no matter what radio button is selected.  I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.  Any suggestions?

```html
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
     <div>
      <h4>Filter</h4>
     </div>
     <div>
      Category:<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category_filter" value="all" checked="checked">&nbsp;All</input><br />
      <input type="radio" name="category_filter" value="accessory">&nbsp;Accessory<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category_filter" value="hardware">&nbsp;Hardware<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category_filter" value="mobile">&nbsp;Mobile App<br />
      <input type="radio" name="category_filter" value="software">&nbsp;Software<br />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_3_of_6">
     <h4>Products</h4>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="accessory" data-quantity="9">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/backpack.jpg" alt="Backpack thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">The NeverNot Backpack</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$75.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="accessory" data-quantity="100">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/bag.jpg" alt="Bag thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">The NeverNot Bag</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$45.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="software">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_business.jpg" alt="NeverNot Premium thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot Premium 1-month Subscription</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$8.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="software">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_business.jpg" alt="NeverNot Business thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot Business Subscription</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$125.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="mobile">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_premium.jpg" alt="NeverNot Premium thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot for iPad</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$4.99</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="software">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_business.jpg" alt="NeverNot Premium thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot Premium 1-year Subscription</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$39.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="mobile">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_premium.jpg" alt="NeverNot Premium thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot for iPhone</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$1.99</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="mobile">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/nevernot_premium.jpg" alt="NeverNot Premium thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot for Android</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$1.99</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="2">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/scanner.jpg" alt="Scanner thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">ScanSnap NeverNot Edition</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$225.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="hardware" data-quantity="12">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/stylus.jpg" alt="Stylus thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">NeverNot Stylus</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$75.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

     <div class="product_listing" data-category="accessory" data-quantity="7">
      <a href="detail.html">
      <div class="product_image">
       <img src="img/wallet.jpg" alt="Wallet thumbnail" />
      </div>
      <div class="product_info">
       <div class="product_name">Wallet</div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <div class="product_price">$35.00</div>
      </div>
      </a>
     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_6">
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
```

```
     $(document).ready( function() {

  var products = $('.product_listing');
  var low_quantity = products.filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('quantity') < 20;

    });
$(low_quantity).addClass("inventory_low");

var accessory_products = products.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'accesory';
});
var hardware_products = products.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'hardware';
});
var mobile_products = products.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'mobile';
});
var software_products = products.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('category') == 'software';
});

$('input').on('change', function () {
  switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'all':
      products.show();
      break;
    case 'accessory':
      products.hide();
      accessory_products.show();
      break;
    case 'hardware':
      products.hide();
      hardware_products.show();
      break;
    case 'mobile':
      products.hide();
      mobile_products.show();
      break;
    case 'software':
      products.hide();
      software_products.show();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the markup as well?

Comment: However `products.show(accessory_products);` is not right.  `show` does not take elements.  Change it to `accessory_products.show();`  http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: `return $(this).data('category') = 'accesory';`  Single `=` is assignment also.  These should be `==` for equality check.

Comment: I agree with @Taplar, let's see the markup.  Your switch statement should at least fire, provided your checkbox inputs have actual values.

Comment: I attempted to add the markup. sorry if it's kinda messy

Comment: Also, accessory_products was the variable not element I think.  Would I still need to change the switch statement to your first comment?

Comment: I changed from single = to == and changed all to be like accessory_products.show() in the switch statement.  Still nothing is happening.

Comment: I just updated it for ya

Comment: I just don't understand why it's not doing anything at all. Seems like somethings off

Comment: You have some syntax errors.  Your change event handler binding is not properly closed.  And you are not closing your document ready.  I fixed the syntax errors in a jsfiddle and it works fine.  Open your browser console and you should see it complaining about the syntax errors.

Comment: I was wondering about that.  But it seemed like everything was closed.  Can you show me the jsfiddle so I can see what to fix?

Comment: Open your console.  Also look at your script.  `$('input').on('change', function () {` has to be closed with a `});`  Find the matching } for that open { and fix that.  Same thing with the document ready.  This is the big reason why people indent their code, so they can quickly find the closing characters for methods and such.  Use what ya got, :)  I would give you the fiddle, but you said this is homework, so i'm going to make you dig.

Comment: Haha thank you so much! Finally got it working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `.show()` function can’t take any arguments or elements -what ever you need to call it- so `products.show(accesory_products);` is totally wrong beacuse what it will do is: do nothing with the argument you give and show products. Thats what it is, so make it like this `accesory_products.show();` hope it helps !

Comment: I did that and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I would say if possible try to avoid the switch entirely.  Just filter and show the ones that should be shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var products = $('.product_listing li');
  
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    var thiz = this;
    
    products.hide().filter(function(){
      return thiz.value == 'all' || this.dataset.category == thiz.value;
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="all" checked> All
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="accessory"> Accessories
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="hardware"> Hardware
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="mobile"> Mobile
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="software"> Software
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="product_listing">
    <li data-category="accessory">A1</li>
    <li data-category="accessory">A2</li>
    <li data-category="hardware">H1</li>
    <li data-category="hardware">H2</li>
    <li data-category="mobile">M1</li>
    <li data-category="mobile">M2</li>
    <li data-category="software">S1</li>
    <li data-category="software">S2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it's actually for a web dev class I'm taking and I think the professor wants us to use a switch statement.